# How to download and show on jsp page uploaded image in path config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") in java

Tags: java

My uploaded images are stored in the `.metadata` folder that is created by Eclipse. How to retrieve them? It's showing "page not found error-404"

```
itemName = item.getName();
File savedFile = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"image\\"+itemName);
item.write(savedFile);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should be writting your files into you webapp. If you are running it from Eclipse, then the webapp might be in the .metadata folder, but it still should work as any other webapp.

Static resources are managed directly by the server, you don't need to do anything at all.

Once the file is downloaded (your code seems to be ok), the image will be available in the URL

```
 http://yourserver[:yourport]/yourwebapp/image/itemName  (including the file extension)
```

Comment: What does mean by webapp? i want to make a link for uploding image.<a href="UplodingimageFolder/ImageName">download</a> and uplooding image folder is in webcontent bt it shows 404 error

Comment: sir all images save on webapp directory it doesnt shows on my eclipse navigator folder how to get data from there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `.metadata` is not put in your war file. Put it under `WebContent`, `WebSource`, or similarly named folder (I don't know what is your project setup, but you will find it).

Comment: sir all images save on webapp directory it doesnt shows on my eclipse navigator folder how to get data from there?